# Capitalize the first letter of each word in a string except `in`, `the` `of`

Tags: regex, r, gsub

How can I capitalize first letter of each word except certain words

```
x <- c('I like the pizza', 'The water in the pool')
```

I expect the output to be

```
c('I Like the Pizza', 'The Water in the Pool')
```

Currently I am using

```
gsub('(^|[[:space:]])([[:alpha:]])', '\\1\\U\\2', x, perl=T)
```

Which capitalizes the first letter of each word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a blacklisting approach with a PCRE RegEx:

```
(?<!^)\b(?:the|an?|[io]n|at|with|from)\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b(\pL)
```

This is a [demo of what this regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/fQ3sY9/2).

In R:

```
x <- c('I like the pizza', 'The water in the pool', 'the water in the pool')
gsub("(?<!^)\\b(?:the|an?|[io]n|at|with(?:out)?|from|for|and|but|n?or|yet|[st]o|around|by|after|along|from|of)\\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\b(\\pL)", "\\U\\1", x, perl=T)
## => [1] "I Like the Pizza"      "The Water in the Pool" "The Water in the Pool"
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/jmajK8)

Here is an article [*Words Which Should Not Be Capitalized in a Title*](http://www.superheronation.com/2011/08/16/words-that-should-not-be-capitalized-in-titles/) with some hints on what words to include into the first alternative group.

The RegEx explanation:

- `(?<!^)` - only match the following alternatives if not at the start of a string (I added this restriction as in comments, there is a requirment that ***the first letter should always be capitalized.***)
- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `(?:the|an?|[io]n|at|with(?:out)?|from|for|and|but|n?or|yet|[st]o|around|by|after|along|from|of)` - the whitelist of the **function words** (CAN AND SHOULD BE EXTENDED!)
- `\b` - trailing word boundary
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` - *fail the match* once the function word is matched
- `|` - or...
- `\b(\pL)` - Capture group 1 matching a letter that is a starting letter in the word.

Comment: Do you have some (good) literature on `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` at hand?

Comment: @Jan: You can read on SO: [*How do (*SKIP) or (*F) work on regex?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex). Also, there is a *`Variation for Perl, PCRE and Python: (*SKIP)(*FAIL)`* section at [*The Greatest Regex Trick Ever* rexegg.com page](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html).

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't work for `the water in the pool`. The first letter should always be capitalized.

Comment: Then you need a `(?<!^)` at the beginning.

Comment: thanks for your code is there I used it on French and German adresses. There I ran into a problem as special characters such as `ä,ö,ü,è,é,à` are interpreted as the beginning of words and hence are capitalized in the middle of words. How can I prevent that behaviour of the function and still have the first letter always capitalized?

Comment: @OscarThees Add `(*UCP)` at the start of the pattern to make `\b` and other shorthands Unicode-aware.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The following regex achieves what you are trying to do:

```
\b(?!(?:in|the|of)\b)([a-z])
# look for a word boundary on the left
# assure that in/the/of is not following immediately 
# (including word boundary, thanks to @stribizhev)
# match and capture a lowercase letter
```

These matched letters (in group 1) need to be changed to Uppercase letters. See [a working demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uZ9vC5/3).

In R:

```
sapply(x, gsub, pattern = "\\b(?!(?:in|the|of)\\b)([a-z])", replacement = "\\U\\1", 
  perl = TRUE, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
## [1] "I Like the Pizza"      "The Water in the Pool"
```

Comment: Let's precise: this expression will work, but it won't work as expected.

Comment: @stribizhev: Please enlight me :-)

Comment: I posted another answer, and you can fix yours with the help of mine. I am adding explanation now.

Comment: Ok, since you got an upvote, have [a hint](https://regex101.com/r/uZ9vC5/2) from me. Please fix your expression.

Comment: @stribizhev: Thanks, have added another boundary (correct?).

Comment: I think it is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I am not good with regex, so found an alternative. `d` is a vector of words which needs to be excluded.

We split the string into words using `strsplit` and then check if any of the word matches with the vector `d`, if it doesn't then we capitalize it using the `capitalize` function in the `Hmisc` package.

```
library(Hmisc)
x <- c('I like the pizza', 'The water in the pool')
d <- c("the","of","in")
lapply(strsplit(x, " "), function(x) ifelse(is.na(match(x, d)), capitalize(x),x))

# [[1]]
#[1] "I"     "Like"  "the"   "Pizza"

#[[2]]
#[1] "The"   "Water" "in"    "the"   "Pool"
```

Further you can use `sapply` along with `paste` to get it back as vector of  string

```
a <- lapply(strsplit(x, " "), function(x) ifelse(is.na(match(x, d)), capitalize(x),x))
sapply(a, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ' '))

#[1] "I Like the Pizza"      "The Water in the Pool"
```